# Why do naked mole rats live in colonies with a queen?

Tags: evolution

What was the evolutionary advantage in having queens? Is it because the ones that had queen like tendencies in the new environment had kids that cooperated better giving higher chance of survival of the colony? Do the worker naked mole rats have an evolutionary advantage in not reproducing because it allows them to devote more energy to the long journey to make one of their siblings the new queen?

Comment: Hello! Do you already have a good understanding in [social evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_evolution)? If not, you will probably want to read [this post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/what-if-rb-c-in-hamiltons-rule) first. The above post only talks about how genetic correlation between individuals can lead to social traits. It doesn't talk about behavioural correlation due to [reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(evolution)) for example. Make sure to read all that.

Comment: Then, well... I don't know what's causing social (or apparently social) behaviour in naked mole rats. [Here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-75957-7_10) is an article that will likely bring some light to the discussion